# VS 2010 Express does not recognise .SQL files?

Tags: visual-studio-express, visual-studio-2010

I have the latest version VS2010 express installed and it does not recognise SQL files. The files are opened as plain text. Is there a setting somewhere that will enable VS2010 to view SQL files in some sort of SQL editor?

Thanks

Comment: I want to view SQL files correctly in VS2010 and not as plain text.

Comment: AFAIR the syntax highlighting is quite poor, even the _SQL Server Management Console_ does not highlight basic keywords like `JOIN`

Comment: Its not only about the highlighting of SQL syntax. My install of VS2010 does not recognise .SQL files at all. You should be able to excute .SQL files against a DB from VS2010 but I cannot.

Comment: Then which _Express_ version do you use? _SQL Server_, _Web Developer_, _C#_ etc. or even a combination?

Comment: Web Developer which ships with SQLServer 2008r2 express

Comment: Then you might not have the DB Dev tools integrated (should require more than Express) but can connect the .sql files to be opened in the SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Can i download the Db dev tools from somewhere?

Comment: I don't think that they are separately available but rather bundled. I didn't install the SQL Server Express version along with VS. When installing the SQL Server you should have the option to install DB Dev Tools VS Addon and Management Studio, that's what I did (on second try, as they need a specific SP version of VS2008 - my VS2010 was not affected).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the express addition supports syntax highlighting for .SQL files.

Comment: Im pretty sure it does, as ive seen MVC tutorials showing the executon of edmx.sql files straight to a DB.